# AJAX call delays the loading of the DOM when triggered in $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a particular page that takes a while to load data from a server. What i wish to achieve is avoiding a blank browser screen while the data is being fetched. Instead of a blank screen, the user will have the page template loaded, along with a message saying please wait while data loads.

The way i attempted to achieve this is by separating the loading of the page template from the data by way of ajax call on page load as per below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'script that loads the data',
            success: function(data) {
               $('body').html(data);
            }
        });
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>Please wait while data loads</body>
</html>
```

It seems (in Chrome at least), that even with this manner of separation, the page still displays as blank initially. I tried using `settimeout()` to fire the ajax call after a second or two but that didnt work either.

Something seems to not be truly asynchronous. What exactly is going on here?

Comment: It is hard to tell without being able to check how the parts are actually loaded. My assumption is that `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" />` and other e media in the header of your actual page take long to load, and that those are responsible for the blank page. And that the `ajax` request itself is really fast not being the problem at all.

Comment: its difficult to tell without seeing whats going on. if you dont see the message in body even after a timeout then there is some other error. check your css? also, a second timeout is not that much. maybe it would be also a good idea to hide the message once the new body fully loads. when you set the new body html that will also take time to load the new stuff. for that time, you could keep the message visible.